# What's the best way to remove Registered, Trademark, and Copyright symbols from a string?

Tags: php, string

What's the best way to remove symbols, like the Registered, Trademark, and Copyright symbols from a string?

For instance I'd like to strip the ® out of the following: `$string = 'Can't Touch This®';`

Comment: Loop over the string and just delete non-alphanumerical chars?

Comment: @Robus - that would kill any punctuation, etc. which he might want to preserve.

Comment: AFAIK, There is no Trademark unicode character - just superscript.

Comment: Good point @karim79, but it's ok if punctuation gets nixed. :)

Comment: @Jamie Wong did not know that. I'm honestly not to knowledgeable about dealing with these types of characters.

Comment: @Matchu Durr. Right you are. I was remembering that there is no HTML entity for trademark. Thanks for quick lookup.

Comment: The HTML entity for trademark is `&trade;`...

Answer (score 9):

```
$str = preg_replace("/(™|®|©|&trade;|&reg;|&copy;|&#8482;|&#174;|&#169;)/", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know what you want to remove, then use `str_replace()`

For instance:

```
 $my_string = str_replace(array('®', '™'), array('', ''), $my_string)
```

If you've got a long list of 'forbidden' characters, you could use `array_fill(0, count($forbidden_list), '')`

Comment: The second argument of `str_replace()` can just be a blank string in this case, both are mixed arguments